# custom UIButton with image

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to set accessory view of cell which is `UIButton`. But it is not shown.

Here is the code

```
UIButton *accessory = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[accessory setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell setAccessoryView:accessory];
```

Comment: try [cell.contentView accessory]; and position accessory according to requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `[accessory sizeToFit];` to adjust its size according to the image.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a frame to this accessory like this

```
UIButton *accessory = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[accessory setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
//Set the accessory frame
accessory.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView* accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 50)];
UIImageView* accessoryViewImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
accessoryViewImage.center = CGPointMake(12, 25);
[accessoryView addSubview:accessoryViewImage];
[cell setAccessoryView:accessoryView];
[accessoryViewImage release];
[accessoryView release];
```

just do like this.